# How can one show that no cyclotomic field contains $\sqrt[3]{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

This is a paraphrase of a problem from an old exam that I'm going over.

> Show that for all positive integers $t$, when $\omega$ is a primitive $t$-th root of unity, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ does not lie in the field $\mathbf{Q}\hspace{.02 in}(\omega)$.

How would one show that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, so every subextension is also Galois. However, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How does one calculate the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$? $\:$ I would have naively thought it was cyclic of order 2. $\hspace{.4 in}$

Comment: There are no non-trivial automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$. An automorphism is determined by where it sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and it must be sent to another cube root of 2. But $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the only cube root of 2 in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.